# Why does template<typename T> evaluate to Foo instead of Bar in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, generic-programming

In this code, why does typename T (in the Test(...) function) evaluate to type Foo instead of type Bar? And how can I change it so that it does become type Bar?

```
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
};

template<typename T>
bool Test(T foo)
{
    return (typeid(foo) == typeid(Bar));
}

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo *foo = &bar;
    bool THIS_IS_TRUE = (typeid(*foo) == typeid(Bar));
    bool WHY_ISNT_THIS = Test(*foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Templates are deduced based on the static type rather than the dynamice type. The code is statically bound and created according to what the compiler knows at compile-time, independent of what types are around at run-time. Additionally, when you pass `*foo` by value, you are slicing the object anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Templates are done at compile time and so they can't figure out the runtime type you're passing them.

Anyway, since you're passing by value you're going to be converting and slicing to the object which will lose the information about the original type `Bar`. Try a reference instead:

```
template<typename T>
bool Test(T& foo)
{
    return (typeid(foo) == typeid(Bar));
}
```

`T` will still be deduced to `Foo`, but `typeid(foo)` should be `Bar`.

Comment: Is there any way to get T to become Bar, that way I can use decltype on foo and create a new Bar object?

Comment: @David It sounds like what you want is defeating the point of generic code in the first place. Anyway, just call `Test` with `bar` if you want to do that.

Comment: @David: When you pass a statically typed object of type `Foo` you won't get `T` to become `Bar`! Even if you try to force it using, e.g., `Test<Bar>(*foo)` it won't work because the compiler will refuse to bind a `Foo&` to a `Bar&`.

Answer (score 1):

You must keep the pointer or pass the value by reference, you cannot pass the variable by copy (passing by value).

Try this :

```
template<typename T>
bool Test(T foo)
{
    return (typeid(*foo) == typeid(Bar));
}

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo *foo = &bar;
    bool THIS_IS_TRUE = (typeid(*foo) == typeid(Bar));
    bool WHY_ISNT_THIS = Test(foo);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do doesn't work.  Here is an alternative approach, where I basically build my own type infrastructure:

```
#include <functional>
struct Base {
protected:
  virtual ~Base() {}
  Base() {}
public:
  virtual size_t SizeRequired() const = 0;
  virtual std::function<Base*(unsigned char* buffer)> Constructor() const = 0;
  // note that standard delete is not standards compliant, because the memory
  // was allocated as an array of unsigned char's
  void SelfDelete() {
    SelfDestroy();
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(this);
  }

  // you can also create these things in other storage locations:
  void SelfDestroy() {
    this->~Base();
  }
  static void Delete( Base* b ) {
    if (b)
      b->SelfDelete();
  }
  std::function<Base*()> AllocateAndConstructor() const {
    size_t required = this->SizeRequired();
    auto constructor = this->Constructor();
    return [required, constructor]()->Base* {
      unsigned char* buff = new unsigned char[ required ];
      return constructor( buff );
    };
  }
};

// CRTP class (google CRTP if you are confused what I'm doing)
template<typename Child>
struct BaseHelper: Base {
  static Base* Construct(unsigned char* buffer) {
    return new(buffer) Child();
  }
  static Base* Create() {
    unsigned char* buff = new unsigned char[ sizeof(Child) ];
    return Construct( buff );
  };
  virtual size_t SizeRequired() const {
    return sizeof(Child);
  }
  virtual std::function<Base*(unsigned char* buffer)> Constructor() const {
    return &BaseHelper<Child>::Construct;
  }
};

// use:

struct Bar: BaseHelper<Bar> {
};
struct Foo: BaseHelper<Foo> {
};

Base* test(Base* b) {
  auto creator = b->AllocateAndConstructor();
  return creator();
}
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  Base* b = Bar::Create(); // creates a Bar
  Base* b2 = test(b); // creates another Bar, because b is a Bar
  Base* f = Foo::Create(); // creates a Foo
  Base* f2 = test(f); // creates another Foo, because f is a Foo
  std::cout << (typeid(*b) == typeid(*b2)) << " == 1\n";
  std::cout << (typeid(*f) == typeid(*f2)) << " == 1\n";
  std::cout << (typeid(*f) == typeid(*b)) << " == 0\n";
  Base::Delete(b);
  Base::Delete(b2);
  Base::Delete(f);
  Base::Delete(f2);
  Base::Delete(0); // does not crash
};
```

this means that each run-time instance of a Base carries with it access to the ability to construct instances of Base.  Overriding new and delete might work better than using the above replacement creation and deletion operations, and would let someone create these things on the stack.

I'd advise against this kind of technique unless you know what you are doing.

There are, however, relatively common patterns, like cloning and factories, that are close to the above but a bit less silly.